# How to insert stored procedure value to parameters in other stored procedure

Tags: sql

I have two stored procedures, I want to send value from first stored procedure to variable in second stored procedure.

Here is my code:

```
create procedure proc_pos
@pilihan varchar(3),
@kd varchar (10),
@ket varchar (50)

as
begin
declare @id2 varchar (10)
        select @id2=exec gen_number 'IP'

    if @pilihan='ins' 
        begin 
            insert into posisi 
                values (@id2, @ket,GETDATE(), 'Admin',0)
            update master_number set last_number=@id2
        end
    else if @pilihan='upd'
        begin
        update posisi set kd_pos=@kd, keterangan=@ket
                    where kd_pos=@kd
        end
    else if @pilihan='del'
        begin
            update posisi set is_deleted=1
                where kd_pos=@kd
        end
end
```

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 1):

Create a second procedure:

```
create procedure proc_pos2
as
begin
decalre 
  @pilihan varchar(3),
  @kd varchar (10),
  @ket varchar (50)

  select @pilihan = 'val1',
         @kd  = 'val2',
         @ket = 'val3'

   exec proc_pos @pilihan, @kd, @ket
end
```

and run it:

```
exec proc_pos2
```

It will send to proc_pos values `val1`, `val2`, `val3` as parameters into the second procedure.

You have to change this values to what you need.